# CSS perspective on pseudo elements blocks content lower half on IOS

Tags: css, ios

So i made a simple button with a perspective pseudo element that flips on hover.
This works perfectly well on android and pc, but on iphone/ipad the text is only visible in the upper half.

Also tried adding a span for the text and position it above the stack, same result.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Couldn't find a similar question on stack so far, but should be fixable i reckon.......

PS: i use scss, so it converts including -webkit and other variants..

This is how it looks on appetize.io (and real iphone):

[image]

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in;
  transition: all .4s ease-in;
  z-index: 10;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 12px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(45deg);
  min-height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -10;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-out
}

.btn:hover:after {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(-135deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(-135deg);
  background-color: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">this is unreadable on ios?</div>
```

Comment: Tested it with Firefox debug mode for iPad and iPhone, looks good.

Comment: But doesn't work on a real iphone as you can see in the screenshot. Try this on an iphone or ipad or emulator like appetize..

Comment: After 3 months and even bounty.. still no answer.  Appearently there's a bug is Safari concerning perspective. It not just on pseudo elements.. i'll update with a work-around i found later....